# vine like player with html 5

Tags: javascript, html

How do you make a player similar to whats vine use using HTML 5 tags

```
<video width="600" height="600" loop preload="auto" video poster="img.jpg" controls>
  <source src="my-video-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

What i want to do is following

- Remove control bar
- Add a volume button like in vine player (on hover)
- Overlay div on the bottom to show info (on hover)

Example vine player

```
https://vine.co/v/h7tUrqaWuTB/embed
```

If anyone can give me tip or a tell me place i can get some info on how to do this highly appreciated. Thanks and advance.

Comment: Your link is broken. Could you post one that works?

Comment: @H Khan - sorry about that link fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the on hover div, you would need javascript. The div should be hidden by default using CSS.

```
var divToShow = document.getElementById('divToShow');
var video = document.querySelector('video'); //gets the video element
video.addEventListener('mouseover', function(element) {
    divToShow.style.display = 'block'; //show the div (block could be replaced with any of the display options)
});
video.addEventListener('mouseout', function(element) {
    divToShow.style.display = 'none'; //hide the div
});
```

The New Boston has an HTML5 tutorial that includes four or five videos on video tag customizations using the javascript video api. They may help you with your other issues.

[The New Boston HTML5 Tutorial](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=43&number=27)